Galaxy Trucker: when exactly does a player lose by getting lapped?
In the Galaxy Trucker board game, a player that is being lapped has to concede.
In our last game, the leading player discovered a "free space" card and decided to spent some batteries resulting in lapping some other players. However, the slower players were all able to fly fast enough in order to overtake him back during the resolution of the free space card.
Do the lapped players loose the flight or is the condition only checked after the card is completely resolved?

Ahh... I just found the answer in the quick overview (could not find it in the main rule book)
Conditions are checked when the card has been completely evaluated. In our case the lapped truckers do not lose.
